# Setting Up Air Gapped Conda Repository

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I love anaconda -- I use it daily -- so nice work to entire team! However, I am currently having a problem setting up an offline repository for an isolated network.  Here is exactly what I have tried - I apologize for the length of the post but wanted to be very precise so as to help those who may try and help me:

1. Download  Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
2. Install answering no to the question about modifying my .bashrc
3. Move .condarc into ./anaconda3/.condarc.
4. source ./anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
5. conda activate base
6. conda info output looks like this:

   ```
       active environment : base
      active env location : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3
              shell level : 1
         user config file : /home/tapitts/.condarc
   populated config files : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/.condarc
            conda version : 4.5.11
      conda-build version : 3.15.1
           python version : 3.7.0.final.0
         base environment : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3  (writable)
             channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64  (offline)
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch  (offline)
                         file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                         file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                         file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                         file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
         package cache : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/pkgs
                         /home/tapitts/.conda/pkgs
      envs directories : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/envs
                         /home/tapitts/.conda/envs
              platform : linux-64
            user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 rhel/7.5 glibc/2.17
               UID:GID : 29684:29684
            netrc file : None
          offline mode : True
   ```
7. conda install python=3.6 gives a package plan that **does not include  conda-4.6.8 for python 3.6**.  It is also comparatively short.

If I answer yes the install proceeds and fails at the very last moment because there is no conda module in place where python 3.6 looks for packages.  After this, conda is completely broken, as you would expect, because we are missing the conda module for python 3.6. I can't even do conda info.  I realize that you typically don't want to downgrade the python in the base environment -- however -- the real problem becomes apparent in what follows.  If I alter the .condarc file that restricts the channels to those on disk so that it reaches out to the repository at continuum.io we see the results of conda info are:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/tapitts/.condarc
 populated config files : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.15.1
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          file:///data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
          package cache : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/tapitts/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /data1/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.3.1/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/tapitts/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 rhel/7.5 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 29684:29684
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

The primary difference being that the online web repo will be used first.  Please note that as far as I can tell, having used wget to fetch the repo at repo.continuum.io, the web repo is identical to the file repo on disk.

In this case the package plan for

conda install python=3.6

indicates the **conda module for 3.6 will install** in this case (and everything functions just fine after that as well).  However, the package listing for the install is **completely different** (much, much longer).  That is my primary concern -- I am likely doing something wrong but have not been able to figure out what in my reading and experimenting.  The solutions for the installs should be the same.  If they aren't, then I can likely expect trouble as people on the isolated network begin to install and manage their own, varied local installs tailored to their tasks and work loops.  By the way, the same thing happens with 2018.12.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `conda install python=3.6 conda` in offline mode/local-only channels do?

Comment: The first conda info above (step 6) is offline mode (there is an offline: True statement in the ./anaconda3/.condarc file).  That is the case where it fails to correctly compute the package solution -- no conda-4.6.8 for python 3.6 and a substantially shorter package list.  In my understanding that is "local-only" mode.

Comment: I'm asking what happens if you explicitly ask it to also (re)install `conda` when you attempt to install the Python 3.6. I think that would be the simplest workaround if it worked.

Comment: If I use conda --use-local --offline install python=3.6 conda it does include conda 4.6.8 for python 3.6.  However, it also still gets a very, very different list of other packages to update (which is the primary problem - ostensibly the same repo obtained with wget but different package solution).  For example using the web repo gives about 200 packages to be upgraded, while the offline/local gives only about 30 -- even though the json index files should be identical.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how to deal with that. What I suggested was only to ensure Conda doesn't break with the Python change. Perhaps a subsequent `conda upgrade --all`, but just guessing.